# Unit test reading from Plist in a framework

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I'm trying to ensure the `SDK` I'm delivering as a `framework` works as intended.

I have for that purpose written some unit tests using `XCTests`. I need to read some information out of a `Plist`, but the path always ends up `nil`.

I am using:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"aPList" ofType:@"plist"];
```

I've got the `Plist` copied via the build phase.

Comment: Just a thought, is the target dependency of the plist file set to the test target?

Comment: @OliverM if you mean the target membership, yes.

Comment: I figured out that the file is copied to the xctest result, but not to the framework itself (which is as I expected it, because in my mind that Plist should be added by the end-user-developer). For testing purposes I've added it to the framework target, but the result is iffy. Having to add a target for "real compilation" and another for "compilation for testing" sounds wrong. Is there a better option, maybe in the code I'm writing to access the bundle?

Comment: I don't get the point? You should already have two targets. 1. the framework target and 2. a testing target, so a plist for testing should be in the testing target

Comment: @OliverM indeed, that's how it is. However, that does not really test the behaviour of the class as it will work in an app, since the file is not really where it will end up being in an app...

Answer (score 0):

The user of your SDK generally wouldn't add the plist to the framework, but to their own app (the main bundle). A class from the SDK could be initialised with a NSURL/path to the plist. That way, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aPList" ofType:@"plist"]` works in both unit test and application bundles for obtaining the plist path to be used by the SDK.

Comment: Actually, this is how I had things initially, but I found it did not work in my tests.